# RN - sending events from Native to JS (ReactContext)

Tags: java, react-native

I'm trying to go through the React Native native modules examples and am stuck on one about sending events from native to js. The documentation provides this. I gather this is not just a copy and paste exercise:

```
...
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
...
private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                      String eventName,
                      @Nullable WritableMap params) {
 reactContext
     .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
     .emit(eventName, params);
}

private int listenerCount = 0;

@ReactMethod
public void addListener(String eventName) {
  if (listenerCount == 0) {
    // Set up any upstream listeners or background tasks as necessary
  }

  listenerCount += 1;
}

@ReactMethod
public void removeListeners(Integer count) {
  listenerCount -= count;
  if (listenerCount == 0) {
    // Remove upstream listeners, stop unnecessary background tasks
  }
}
...
WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
params.putString("eventProperty", "someValue");
...
sendEvent(reactContext, "EventReminder", params);
```

I've implemented it as follows:

```
package com.todox;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.util.Log;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;




public class MyEventEmitterModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    MyEventEmitterModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private int listenerCount = 0;

    @ReactMethod
    public void addListener(String eventName) {
        if (listenerCount == 0) {
            // Set up any upstream listeners or background tasks as necessary
        }

        listenerCount += 1;
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void removeListeners(Integer count) {
        listenerCount -= count;
        if (listenerCount == 0) {
            // Remove upstream listeners, stop unnecessary background tasks
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MyEventEmitterModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void initEmitter() {
        Log.d("MEEM", "Initialised the MyEventEmitterModule");
    }

    private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                           String eventName,
                           @Nullable WritableMap params) {
        reactContext
                .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit(eventName, params);
    }



    @ReactMethod
    public void initWithListener(ReactContext reactContext) {
        try {
            WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
            params.putString("eventProperty", "someValueXXXXXXX");

            Log.d("MEEM", "Initialised the MyEventEmitterModule WITH LISTENER");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            sendEvent(reactContext, "EventReminder", params);
            Log.d("MEEM", "AfterSending");

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("MEEM", "EXCEPTION" + e);
        }

    }



}
```

When I tap on the button in the app to call the initWithListener method I get:

```
Exception in native call
java.lang.RuntimeException: Got unknown argument class: ReactContext
```

I kind of understand that it's not going to work as I don't pass any argument to initWithListener from the js land but I can't get it work. ReactContext seems unavailable in that class. How can I make it work, please? My knowledge of java is very basic. Thanks